# The LINQ expression could not be translated error

Tags: c#, database, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a database with two tables, Requests and Authorities. Authorities has a column called AuthorityOf containing a string such as "AAAA" and each request in the Requests table has a column called RequiresAuthorityFrom containing a List such as ["AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC"] (stored as a string in the database and retrieved as a List). I’m trying to write a LINQ query to get all requests from the Requests table where the list RequiresAuthorityFrom contains any of the strings found in the Authorities table column AuthorityOf.

I wrote a query like this:

```cs
var result = _dbContext.Requests
    .Where(req => req.RequiresAuthorityFrom.Any(a => _dbContext.Authorities.Select(auth => auth.AuthorityOf).Contains(a)))
    .ToList();
```

The entity types are as following (simplified versions):

```cs
public class Authority
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AuthorityOf { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonField]
    public List<string> RequiresAuthorityFrom { get; set; }
}
```

The JsonField flag from the package Innofactor.EfCoreJsonValueConverter is used to handle the conversion to and from json in the getter and setter.

It returns the following error:

```
The LINQ expression 'a => DbSet<Authority>()
    .Select(a => a.AuthorityOf)
    .Any(p => object.Equals(
        objA: p, 
        objB: a))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

How can I write a query that does this? I've tried switching to client evaluation by inserting a call to AsEnumerable/ToList but it makes no difference.

Comment: Please provide the corresponding entity types.

Comment: `public List<string> RequiresAuthorityFrom { get; set; }` <-- This is incompatible with how RDBMSs work at a fundamental level...

Comment: `[JsonField]` <-- Don't do this. EF entity classes are not JSON DTO types. Attempting to forcefully use an EF entity class as a DTO is asking for trouble. **EF Entities are not DTOs**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by modifying the entity according to the comments like this:

```
public class Request
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RequiresAuthorityFrom { get; set; }
}
```

And rewrote the query like this:

```
var result = _dbContext.Requests.Where(x => _dbContext.Authorities.Select(a => a.AuthorityOf).Any(a => x.RequiresAuthorityFrom.Contains(a))).OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would change this:

```
var result = _dbContext.Requests.Where(req => req.RequiresAuthorityFrom.Any(a => _dbContext.Authorities.Select(auth => auth.AuthorityOf).Contains(a))).ToList();
```

to this:

```
var result = _dbContext.Requests.Where(req => req.RequiresAuthorityFrom.Any(a => _dbContext.Authorities.Any(auth => auth.AuthorityOf == a))).ToList();
```

And if that can not be translated (since not sure how `JsonField` attribute is handled) then I would consider client evaluation.

But, as mentioned in comments, it's a bad idea to decorate Entities with stuff that should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to get all the distinct authorities first? Assuming that their count is limited:

```
var distinctAuthorities = _dbContext.Authorities.Select(auth => auth.AuthorityOf).Distinct();


var result = _dbContext.Requests
    .Where(req => req.RequiresAuthorityFrom.Any(a => distinctAuthorities.Contains(a)))
    .ToList();
```

By fetching the distinct authorities to filter the requests later on, chances are that you will reduce a number of db queries and improve performance.